# where to link g++ libraries while using python install command

Tags: python, g++

I have an installation here using the command `python setup.py install`

This is giving me an error:

```
/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'overfeat' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I../../src -I/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/sandesh/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c overfeatmodule.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/overfeatmodule.o -fopenmp
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                 from /home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from overfeatmodule.cpp:4:
/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
g++ -pthread -shared -L/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/overfeatmodule.o -L../../src -L/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib -lTH -loverfeat -lopenblas -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/overfeat.so -lgomp -l/home/sandesh/Downloads/overfeat/src/libTH.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/sandesh/Downloads/overfeat/src/libTH.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I've searched on the Internet and found I need to link g++ libraries (correct me if I'm wrong). But I'm not able to understand where to include the extra command like this `-L/usr/lib -lopenblas`

```
sandesh@sandesh-H87M-D3H:~/Downloads/overfeat/API/python$ python setup.py -L/usr/lib -lopenblas install
/home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option -L not recognized
```

Comment: You need to install a package that contains libopenblas.

Comment: In addition, `-l/home/sandesh/Downloads/overfeat/src/libTH.a` is wrong. Remove the initial `-l`.